# What does "max txn-txn-inflight limit reached" in QuestDb, and how to I avoid it?

Tags: questdb

I occasionally get "txn-txn-inflight limit reached [txn=251584, min=240384]" on servers when attempting to read data from (embedded) QuestDb.

It self corrects after some time (minutes). What does it mean and what can I do to avoid it?

Comment: This could be caused by resource leak emanating from your code. I would double check that resources such as `RecordCursorFactory`, `RecordCursor` and `TableReader` are closed after use. The large spread between `txn` and `min` could indicate that active `TableReader` instances are present. Unless you're expecting 10k simultaneous queries - I would assume a leak.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing `_txn_scoreboard` file in table's directory. This file has no meaning unless process is running.

The contents of this file is used to indicate if there is active `TableReader` holding a view on particular data transaction. When Java process exists, `TableReader` instances returned to pool will clock down their transaction number to prevent false-positive "reader holding transaction X'.

If Java process is crashed or did not return `TableReader` to pool, the transaction numbers can appear to be in-use next time application starts. The only work around so far is to remove `_txn_scoreboard` file.

Comment: Thank you, removing that file and restarting the process resolves the issue. So, is this a known error? We never saw it until we upgraded from 5 to 6.0.2.

Comment: This is a new functionality in 6.0.x. We are fixing this issue for good in 6.0.4

Comment: @VladIlyushchenko I use questdb image v6.0.4 but still see this error happen. We use REST API, not Java one though.